# How this Full GC triggered while new and old generation seems still big enough?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I checked the GC logs, after a server recycle and wondering how the FUll GC happened at 70s while new and old generation seems still big enough. Can anyone hep to figure it out?

> 65.024: [GC [PSYoungGen: 323666K->14524K(334336K)] 363447K->86509K(1033408K), 0.2293691 secs] [Times: user=1.04 sys=0.36,
>   real=0.23 secs]
>
> 69.092: [GC [PSYoungGen: 334332K->5367K(309376K)] 406317K->91976K(1008448K), 0.1135844 secs] [Times: user=0.47 sys=0.17,
>   real=0.11 secs]
>
> 69.966: [GC [PSYoungGen: 87013K->1309K(321856K)] 173623K->92893K(1020928K), 0.0460899 secs] [Times: user=0.26 sys=0.06,
>   real=0.05 secs]
>
> 70.013: [Full GC (System) [PSYoungGen: 1309K->0K(321856K)] [PSOldGen: 91584K->92406K(699072K)] 92893K->92406K(1020928K) [PSPermGen:
>   87510K->87510K(175104K)], 1.1467688 secs] [Times: user=1.15 sys=0.00,
>   real=1.15 secs]